# Configuring GitHub Copilot to work with C# Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Are there any defaults that can be set to have copilot work well with C# in Visual Studio? I have problems with it changing BCL method calls to lower case. This strikes me as a low hanging fruit problem. Thanks in advance.